# Am I doing something wrong in my file-reader function?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner to C and wanted to code a simple function that reads the content of file and returns it as a string, as an exercise.

Here is my solution which I think works, but is there any obvious bad practices or unoptimal code here ? For example, I manually added a \0 at the end of the string, but I don't know if it is really necessary...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readFile(char *path)
{
    //open file
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    //if broken
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erreur");
        return NULL;
    }

    //return variable
    char *result;

    //length of the file
    int len;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //initialising return variable
    result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while (feof(file) == 0)
    {
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            printf("%04x -> %c\n", c, c);
            *(result + i) = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *(result + i) = '\0';
    printf("len : %i\n", len);
    fclose(file);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Better loop control could be with `while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)`. Also if you want to turn a (text) file content into a string, then you *must* add the `'\0'`.

Comment: A string needs to be null terminated. So if there is no null character at the end of the string, you obviously must put one yourself. Side note: don't write `*(result + i)`  but rather `result[i]`. It's more readable and it's the idiomatic way. Side note 2: the casts are not necessary with `malloc`, instead of `(char*) malloc` just write `malloc`. The cast is not wrong, but just not necessary, and it adds no value whatsoever to readability or whatever.

Comment: Another way would be to read the entire file with a single call to `fread()` (and again write the NUL terminator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replace this:

```
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while (feof(file) == 0)
    {
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            printf("%04x -> %c\n", c, c);
            *(result + i) = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

with this:

```
    fread(file, 1, len, result);
```

- It's much shorter
- It's correct
- It's certainly faster

There is still room for improvement though, for example you could add error handling, `fread` can fail.

Comment: Note that on systems that cook the newline characters, e.g. Windows text files in mode `"t"` (or perhaps in default mode) the count returned by `fread` may not be the same as the size reported by `ftell`. So terminate the data at the offset provided by `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already got the length of the file to be read, you could also read them at once instead char-by-char.

Another implmentation of your function, for example:

```
char *readFile(char *path)
{
    //open file
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    //if broken
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erreur");
        return NULL;
    }

    //return variable
    char *result;

    //length of the file
    int len;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //initialising return variable
    result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

    size_t i = fread(result, sizeof(char), len, file);

    *(result + i) = '\0';
    printf("len : %i\n", len);
    fclose(file);

    return result;
}
```